# need to understand the ur to path converter in Django

Tags: django, url, path

i am learn to Django . i have stuking the below URL . i use path but i went to convert it to my path URL pattern .

This is my actual Path patrn

```
path('', views.home,name='home'),
path('topics/<int:id>/', views.board_topic, name='topics'), 
path('topics/<int:id>/new/', views.new_topic,name='new_topic'), 
path('signup/', accounts_views.signup, name='signup'),
```

i went to convert below this comented url to the below path

```
path('topics/<int:id>/topic_id', views.topic_posts, name='topic_posts'),


# url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/topics/(?P<topic_pk>\d+)/$', views.topic_posts, name='topic_posts'),
```

This is Good Formate ? if not then which is best url to path formate ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'url' is the old version of 'path' used in versions  < Django 2.0. This is what it would look like using the more recent 'path' instead.
    `path('boards/<int:pk>/topics/<int:topic_pk>/', views.topic_posts, name='topic_posts'),`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
path('boards/<int:pk>/topics/<int:topic_pk>/', views.topic_posts, name='topic_posts'),
```

If you need different types you can choose from this list or create custom converters. The following path converters are available by default:

- `str` - Matches any non-empty string, excluding the path separator, '/'.
- `int` - Matches zero or any positive integer. Returns an int.
- `slug` - Matches any slug string consisting of ASCII letters or numbers, plus the hyphen and underscore characters. For example, building-your-1st-django-site.
- `uuid` - Matches a formatted UUID.
- `path` - Matches any non-empty string, including the path separator, '/'. This allows you to match against a complete URL path rather than a segment of a URL path as with str.